# Where can I find the source code for the com.sun.jdi package?

Tags: java, jdi

I wanna to see how to debug the java code using jdi, but i don't know where to get the source code about it. is it in jdk? I have used eclipse to import the src.zip in jdk but that seems doesn't contain the infomation about jdi, where can i find it?

Comment: The usual routine for finding open source code is to google ["grepcode com.sun.jdi"](https://www.google.com/search?q=grepode+com.sun.jdi&oq=grepode+com.sun.jdi&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.5718j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which turns up several pages that look like [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/jdi/VirtualMachineImpl.java).  I don't know if every JDK is going to use the same implementation of these classes, however...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the source for the OpenJDK implementation of the package [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/).  Just use the tree view on the left to select the package you want.